# scala spark - mapGroup - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Iterator[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dept dataset and a salary dataset as below, I want to combine both the dataset using caseclass
and the output as the third table.

For this purpose I am joining both the datasets and then executing a groupByKey on the joined dataset

The output of the groupByKey is `org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[Int,(Dept, Sal)]` .

I would like to
convert it back to a dataset to the below case class format.

However I am receiving the below error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Iterator[String]
> - field (class: "scala.collection.Iterator", name: "_2")

please help.

```scala
case class DeptSals(deptNo :Int, dname: String ,sals : Seq[Sal])

case class Dept(deptNo :Int, dname: String)

case class Sal(deptNo :Int, Ename: String,sal:Long)

val deptDS = Seq(Dept(1,"ANALYST"),Dept(2,"HR"),Dept(3,"FINANCE"),Dept(4,"CLERK"),Dept(5,"MANAGER")).toDS

val salDS = Seq(Sal(2,"Amelia",4000),Sal(2,"Cherry",4000),Sal(3,"Carl",7000),Sal(4,"John",6000),Sal(5,"Rick",1000)).toDS
```

Department Dataset:

```
scala> deptDS.show
+------+-------+
|deptNo|  dname|
+------+-------+
|     1|ANALYST|
|     2|     HR|
|     3|FINANCE|
|     4|  CLERK|
|     5|MANAGER|
+------+-------+
```

Sal Dataset:

```
+------+------+----+
|deptNo| Ename| sal|
+------+------+----+
|     2|Cherry|4000|
|     2|Amelia|4000|
|     3|  Carl|7000|
|     4|  John|6000|
|     5|  Rick|1000|
+------+------+----+
```

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val deptJoinSalDS = deptDS.joinWith(salDS,deptDS("deptNo") ===   salDS("deptNo"),"left_outer").groupByKey(x => x._1.deptNo).mapGroups{ case(k,v) => ( k,v.map( _._1.dname), v.map( _._2.Ename)) }
```

need output as

```
+------+---------------------------------+-------+
|deptNo|Sals                             | sumSal|
+------+---------------------------------+-------+
|     1|                                 |      0|
|     2|[[2,Amelia,4000],[2,Cherry,4000]]|   8000|
|     3|[[3,Carl,4000]]                  |   4000|
|     4|[[4,John,6000]]                  |   6000|
|     5|[[5,Rick,1000]]                  |   1000|
+------+---------------------------------+-------+
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Iterator[String]
> - field (class: "scala.collection.Iterator", name: "_2")
> - root class: "scala.Tuple3" `

Comment: val deptSals = deptJoinSalDS.mapGroups{ case (k,iter) => {

     val listBufferSalCls = new ListBuffer[Sal]
     val listBuffersal = new ListBuffer[Double]
     
  for (x <- iter) 
  {

   if (x._2 != null)
   {
    listBufferSalCls += x._2
    listBuffersal += x._2.sal //lowercase sal
   }
  }
  DeptSal(k,listBufferSalCls,listBuffersal.sum)
}
}
 
deptSals.show(10,false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below answer solves the problem of iterating over sequence of two classes.

There were two issues

1. The first issue was that whenever I performed a join of two datasets it was returning a (key, iterator of (Dept,Sal) classes. I was iterating over two classes and using "map" on each of these iterators. I used to get empty values in returned Dataset as output.
2. So I was trying with some other approach and I ended up in this error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Iterator[String]

I was able to fix this after I learnt that the empty values are because we can't use "map" function multiple times in an iterator and the values are lost. We can use listBuffer to store the values and then return in "mapGroups"

```
case class Dept(deptNo :Int, dname: String)

case class Sal(deptNo :Int, Ename: String,sal:Long)


val deptDS = Seq(Dept(1,"ANALYST"),Dept(2,"HR"),Dept(3,"FINANCE"),Dept(4,"CLERK"),Dept(5,"MANAGER")).toDS

val salDS = Seq(Sal(2,"Amelia",4000),Sal(2,"Cherry",4000),Sal(3,"Carl",7000),Sal(4,"John",6000),Sal(5,"Rick",1000)).toDS

val deptJoinSalDS = deptDS.joinWith(salDS,deptDS("deptNo") === salDS("deptNo"),"left_outer").groupByKey(x => x._1.deptNo)

case class DeptSal(deptNo :Int,SalSeq: Seq[Sal],salSum:Double)


val deptSals = deptJoinSalDS.mapGroups{ case (k,iter) => {

     val listBufferSalCls = new ListBuffer[Sal]
     val listBuffersal = new ListBuffer[Double]
     
     for (x <- iter) 
     {

      if (x._2 != null)
      {
       listBufferSalCls += x._2
       listBuffersal += x._2.sal //lowercase sal
      }
     }
     DeptSal(k,listBufferSalCls,listBuffersal.sum)
}
}
     

scala> deptSals.show(10,false)
+------+--------------------------------------+------+
|deptNo|SalSeq                                |salSum|
+------+--------------------------------------+------+
|1     |[]                                    |0.0   |
|2     |[{2, Cherry, 4000}, {2, Amelia, 4000}]|8000.0|
|3     |[{3, Carl, 7000}]                     |7000.0|
|4     |[{4, John, 6000}]                     |6000.0|
|5     |[{5, Rick, 1000}]                     |1000.0|
+------+--------------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: It's not clear if this is an answer that solves the problem. If that is the case, please add some details explaining what was the issue and why this code solves the problem

Comment: Hi Gaston thanks for following up Yes this an answer that solves the problem of iterating over sequence of two classes. There were two issues 

1. The first issue was that whenever I performed a join of two datasets it was returning a (key, iterator of (Dept,Sal) classes. 

I was iterating over two classes  and using "map" on each of these iterators. I used to get empty values in returned Dataset as output.

 2. So I was trying with some other approach and I ended up in this error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Iterator[String]

Comment: I was able to fix this after I learnt that the empty values are because we can't use "map" function multiple times in an iterator and the values are lost. We can use listBuffer to store the values and then return in "mapGroups"

Comment: Got it. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76646905/edit) detailing what you explained here in the comments. If it is possible add links to docs or articles that endorse your answer. Also try to format the provided code. The article [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might help you